# LOAD DATA INFILE and LINESTRING

Tags: mysql

I want to import large CSV file with following columns

```
SegmentId;Lengthmm;RoadClass;OptimalSpeedKph;SpeedLimitKph;WKT
1;7329;1;120;70;LINESTRING (28.97845 41.067332,28.978537 41.067332)
...
```

I am using LOAD DATA INFILE. Problem is that `WKT` is LINESTRING.
Actually if I add one entry with following query:

```
INSERT INTO FCD 
VALUES (3,1,1,1,1,LineStringFromText( 'LINESTRING (28.947971 41.050192,28.94754 41.049887)'));
```

It is inserted into table.

However I didn't know to access the WKT parameter in LOAD DATA INFILE command and transform it.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/username/userfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE `FCD` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
       ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

With regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable to load the value from the WKT column and use the `SET` clause of the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) statement to use the value of the variable in an expression and assign it to a column:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/username/userfile.csv'
INTO TABLE `FCD`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
       ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(SegmentId, Lengthmm, RoadClass, OptimalSpeedKph, SpeedLimitKph, @WKT)
SET WKT = LineStringFromText(@WKT)
```

I assumed the first line of the CSV file contains the names of the table columns. Remark the last field in the list is `@WKT` which is a variable then the `SET` clause that uses the value of variable `@WKT` into an expression then assign it to column `WKT`.

Comment: I will also try your solution. Now I am trying the earlier answer, but my file contains 12M entries. I will answer as long it is finished

Answer (score 0):

Create a staging table where WKT is a string. Then run

```
INSERT INTO FCD 
     SELECT SegmentId, Lengthmm, RoadClass, OptimalSpeedKph, SpeedLimitKph, LineStringFromText (WKT) 
      FROM FCD_staging;
```